# How to deal with RAM limitations when working with big datasets in R?

Tags: r, logistic, dataset, large-data

I am currently playing around with the MNIST dataset (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) in R. The training set size is 60000x748 and it seems to drain all my memory even when constructing simple models like logistic regression.

My question is: how do you guys usually deal with big datasets in R?

And tangent: is it feasible to break the dataset into smaller chunks, construct a model on each, then perform a weighted average on the predicted values?

Comment: Maybe that's trivial, but using the garbage collection `gc()` sometimes helps. I had some calculations where I had to use `gc` 4 times within a function - but then it worked.

Comment: Your second question would be qualified as more on-topic than the first, IMO.

Comment: Are you running in l

Comment: You might find some good tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session

Answer (score 4):

I rely on having a 64-bit operating system and running 64-bit R and even then I still crash.

Depending on what you want to do, have a look at this [CRAN site](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html). Unfortunately because my large data frame was using mixed methods, `biglm` wasn't any good for me. I read up on `ff` and it didn't suit my needs either, because the method it uses to save and retrieve to and from disk space won't work with a number of analysis methods I am using. The `bigmemory` and associated packages don't appear to be completely compatible with data frames, although matrices appear handled easily enough.